# tkinter create labels and entrys dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a simple GUI where I can enter some values. A label before and at the and an button to start the script.

I was using something like this:

```
w = Label(master, text="weight:")
w.grid(sticky=E)
w = Label(root, text="bodyfathydrationmuscle:bones")
w.grid(sticky=E)
w = Label(root, text="hydration:")
w.grid(sticky=E)
```

its ok but i want to do it dynamic. also when i would use w for all the entrys i only could cast w.get once. but i need all my data ;-)

i was thinking of:

```
  def create_widgets(self):
    L=["weight","bodyfat","hydration","muscle","bones"]
    LV=[]
    for index in range(len(L)):
        print(index)
        print(L[index])
        ("Entry"+L[index])= Entry(root)
        ("Entry"+L[index]).grid(sticky=E)
        ("Label"+L[index])=Label(root, text=L[index])
        ("Label"+L[index]).grid(row=index, column=1)
```

To call later:

```
var_weight=Entryweight.get()
var_bodyfat=Entrybodyfat.get()
```

and so on. how can i make it work?

Answer (score 9):

Your program suggests that `Entrybodyfat` and the other variables should be [generated on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python), but you don't want to do that.

The normal approach is to store the entries and labels in a list or a map:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

names = ["weight", "bodyfat", "hydration", "muscle", "bones"]
entry = {}
label = {}

i = 0
for name in names:
    e = Entry(root)
    e.grid(sticky=E)
    entry[name] = e

    lb = Label(root, text=name)
    lb.grid(row=i, column=1)
    label[name] = lb
    i += 1

def print_all_entries():
    for name in names:
        print entry[name].get()

b = Button(root, text="Print all", command=print_all_entries)
b.grid(sticky=S)

mainloop()
```

The value of the bodyfat entry is then `entry["bodyfat"].get()`.