# Python>tkinter: How to get values from a panel inside a notebook frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just beginning to program in python and I'm using it to make a little program with an GUI (using tkinter) that can take data from an excel file (using openpyxl). Let the user change things when necesarry and then use a button to write the data from the entries to a data file (.dat) (preferable by updating the values in the defaultdict arrays and then write the .dat file) and use a modelling language (pyomo) to create a model with the provided data and solve it with the cbc solver.

I'm now sofar that I made the model, the graphical interface (which is filled with data from the excel file). However I can't get the data in the entries fields back (to write update the defaultdicts arrays). I understand the simple examples on stackoverflow (with entry.get()), but it didn't worked on my example (probably because I use notbook tabs, panels and frames or I messed something up).

I use notebook tabs instead of one page, because I will have more (around 5) other categories of data in the complete program. At last I want to make the programm is such a way that it can adapt to the input (so it does not know if there are going to be 3, 8 or 10 facilities). I use python version 3.5.1. Here is the link to the excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5vmtJnltudJWW4xakZlYnQ3RTg/view?usp=sharing

```
    import sys
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter as tk
    import openpyxl
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from collections import defaultdict
    from facility_panel import *

    class App(tk.Tk):


        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.getdata()
            self.tabes()
            button_box = tk.Frame(self)
            tk.Button(button_box, text='Create Planning', command=self.on_ok_clicked).grid(pady=15)
            button_box.pack()

            self.create_menu()
            self.set_keybindings()

        @staticmethod
        def center_on_screen(toplevel):
            toplevel.update_idletasks()
            w = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth()
            h = toplevel.winfo_screenheight()
            size = tuple(int(_) for _ in toplevel.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
            x = w/2 - size[0]/2
            y = h/2 - size[1]/2
            toplevel.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (size + (x, y)))


        def set_keybindings(self):
            self.bind_all('<Control-o>', lambda event: self.open_file())
            self.bind_all('<Control-s>', lambda event: self.save_file())
            self.bind_all('<Control-q>', self.quit_app)
            self.bind_all('<Control-h>', lambda event: self.show_help())
            self.bind_all('<Return>', lambda event: self.on_ok_clicked())


        def on_ok_clicked(self):
            print ('Entry text: %s' % self.entry.get())
            print ('Scale value: %.1f' % self.scale.get())
            print ('Checkbutton value: %i' % self.checkbox_val.get())
            print ('Spinbox value: %i' % int(self.spinbox.get()))
            print ('OptionMenu value: %s' % self.enum_val.get()) 


        def create_menu(self):
            menubar = tk.Menu(self)

            fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
            menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", underline=1, command=self.open_file, accelerator="Ctrl+O")
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", underline=1, command=self.save_file, accelerator="Ctrl+S")
            fileMenu.add_command(label="Quit", underline=1, command=self.quit_app, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")

            helpMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
            menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", underline=0, menu=helpMenu)
            helpMenu.add_command(label="Help", underline=1, command=self.show_help, accelerator="Ctrl+H")
            helpMenu.add_command(label="About", underline=1, command=self.about_app)
            self.config(menu=menubar)


        def open_file(self):
            """Options are explained here: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog"""
            filename = askopenfilename(title='Open a file')
            if filename:
                print ('Open and do something with %s' % filename)


        def save_file(self):
            """Options are explained here: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog"""
            filename = asksaveasfilename()
            if filename:
                print ('Save something to %s' % filename)


        def quit_app(self):
            app.destroy()


        def show_help(self):
            # FIXME: pressing return correctly closes dialog, but also incorrectly fires the main window's 'on_click' method
            about_text = """
            Contact: \n
            example@hotmail.com"""
            about_dialog = tk.Toplevel(self)
            about_dialog.title('About App')
            about_dialog.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: about_dialog.destroy())
            about_dialog.bind('<Return>', lambda event: about_dialog.destroy())
            App.center_on_screen(about_dialog)
            tk.Message(about_dialog, text=about_text).pack()
            button = tk.Button(about_dialog, text='Close', command=about_dialog.destroy).pack()


        def about_app(self):
            # FIXME: pressing return correctly closes dialog, but also incorrectly fires the main window's 'on_click' method
            about_text = """
            This application is made by Jan Jansen\n
            version 0.7"""
            about_dialog = tk.Toplevel(self)
            about_dialog.title('About App')
            about_dialog.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: about_dialog.destroy())
            about_dialog.bind('<Return>', lambda event: about_dialog.destroy())
            App.center_on_screen(about_dialog)
            tk.Message(about_dialog, text=about_text).pack()
            button = tk.Button(about_dialog, text='Close', command=about_dialog.destroy).pack()

        def tabes(self):
            nb = ttk.Notebook()
            nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")


                    # Frame to hold contentx
            frame = tk.Frame(nb)

            vscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
            #panel['yscroll'] = vscroll.set
            vscroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

            for facilityname in Facilities:
                panel = FacilityPanel(frame, facilityname, capfacility[facilityname], safetystock[facilityname], maxpressure[facilityname], str(compulsorystarttime[facilityname]),  str(compulsoryendtime[facilityname]), demandmatrix[facilityname][1], demandmatrix[facilityname][2], demandmatrix[facilityname][3], demandmatrix[facilityname][4], demandmatrix[facilityname][5], demandmatrix[facilityname][6], demandmatrix[facilityname][7])
                panel.pack(fill="both")


            # add to notebook (underline = index for short-cut character)
            nb.add(frame, text='Facilities', underline=0, padding=2)


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        def getdata(self):
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("data.xlsx")


                ws = wb["Facilities"]
                global Facilities
                Facilities = ([])
                row_count = ws.max_row
                column_count = ws.max_column
                global initlevel
                initlevel = defaultdict(dict)
                global capfacility
                capfacility = defaultdict(dict)
                global safetystock
                safetystock = defaultdict(dict)
                global maxpressure
                maxpressure = defaultdict(dict)
                global pressureincrease
                pressureincrease = defaultdict(dict)
                global compulsorystarttime
                compulsorystarttime = defaultdict(dict)
                global compulsoryendtime
                compulsoryendtime = defaultdict(dict)
                global demandmatrix
                demandmatrix = defaultdict(dict)
                for i in range(3, row_count+1, 1):
                      Facilities.append(ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value)
                      initlevel[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 2).value
                      capfacility[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 3).value
                      safetystock[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 4).value
                      maxpressure[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 5).value
                      pressureincrease[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 6).value
                      compulsorystarttime[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 7).value
                      compulsoryendtime[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value]  = ws.cell(row = i, column = 8).value
                      for j in range (9, column_count+1, 1):
                         demandmatrix[ws.cell(row = i, column = 1).value][ws.cell(row = 2, column = j).value] = ws.cell(row = i, column = j).value


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = App()
        app.title("Planning")
        toplevel = app.winfo_toplevel()
        toplevel.wm_state('zoomed')
        app.mainloop()
```

And this is the class I made:
        from tkinter import *

```
    class FacilityPanel(Frame):
        def __init__(self, app, facility_name, capacity, safetystock, maxpressure, compulsorystarttime, compulsoryendtime, demandma, demanddi, demandwo, demanddo, demandvr, demandza, demandzo):
            Frame.__init__(self, app)

            group = LabelFrame(self, text=facility_name)
            group.pack(side =LEFT)

            group.enable_facility = IntVar()
            enable_button = Checkbutton(group, variable = group.enable_facility,
                command = print("toggle"))
            enable_button.pack(side = LEFT)
            enable_button.select()

            group.init_level = IntVar()
            init_label = Label(group, text="Current Level: 5,06 m\u00B3")
            init_label.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.capacity = DoubleVar()
            capacity_label = Label(group, text="Capacity:")
            capacity_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            capacity_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            capacity_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            capacity_entry.insert(0, capacity)
            capacity_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            capacity_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.safetystock = DoubleVar()
            safetystock_label = Label(group, text="Safetystock:")
            safetystock_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            safetystock_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            safetystock_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            safetystock_entry.insert(0, safetystock)
            safetystock_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            safetystock_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.maxpressure = DoubleVar()
            maxpressure_label = Label(group, text="Maxpressure:")
            maxpressure_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            maxpressure_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            maxpressure_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            maxpressure_entry.insert(0, maxpressure)
            maxpressure_label_unit = Label(group, text="bar ")
            maxpressure_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.comp_start_time = DoubleVar()
            comp_time1_label = Label(group, text="Unload time window:")
            comp_time1_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            comp_start_time_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            comp_start_time_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            comp_start_time_entry.insert(0, compulsorystarttime)
            comp_time2_label = Label(group, text="-")
            comp_time2_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            comp_end_time_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            comp_end_time_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            comp_end_time_entry.insert(0, compulsoryendtime)
            comp_time3_label = Label(group, text="hours           ")
            comp_time3_label.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demandmaandag = DoubleVar()
            demandmaandag_label = Label(group, text="Maandag:")
            demandmaandag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandmaandag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demandmaandag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandmaandag_entry.insert(0, demandma)
            demandmaandag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demandmaandag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demanddinsdag = DoubleVar()
            demanddinsdag_label = Label(group, text="Dinsdag:")
            demanddinsdag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demanddinsdag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demanddinsdag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demanddinsdag_entry.insert(0, demanddi)
            demanddinsdag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demanddinsdag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demandwoensdag = DoubleVar()
            demandwoensdag_label = Label(group, text="Woensdag:")
            demandwoensdag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandwoensdag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demandwoensdag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandwoensdag_entry.insert(0, demandwo)
            demandwoensdag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demandwoensdag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demanddonderdag = DoubleVar()
            demanddonderdag_label = Label(group, text="Donderdag:")
            demanddonderdag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demanddonderdag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demanddonderdag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demanddonderdag_entry.insert(0, demanddo)
            demanddonderdag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demanddonderdag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demandvrijdag = DoubleVar()
            demandvrijdag_label = Label(group, text="Vrijdag:")
            demandvrijdag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandvrijdag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demandvrijdag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandvrijdag_entry.insert(0, demandvr)
            demandvrijdag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demandvrijdag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demandzaterdag = DoubleVar()
            demandzaterdag_label = Label(group, text="Zaterdag:")
            demandzaterdag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandzaterdag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demandzaterdag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandzaterdag_entry.insert(0, demandza)
            demandzaterdag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demandzaterdag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)

            group.demandzaterdag = DoubleVar()
            demandzondag_label = Label(group, text="Zondag:")
            demandzondag_label.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandzondag_entry = Entry(group, width=8)
            demandzondag_entry.pack(side = LEFT)
            demandzondag_entry.insert(0, demandzo)
            demandzondag_label_unit = Label(group, text="kg ")
            demandzondag_label_unit.pack(side = LEFT)
```

Comment: TL;DR. Too much information and code. Please edit your post to contain the *minimum* information and code necessary to demonstrate your problem. Openpyxl and pyomo, and cbc solver do not seem to be relevant to the issue at hand, so need not be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked on this question:
[tkinter create labels and entrys dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300041/tkinter-create-labels-and-entrys-dynamically)

I made a global entry for every entryfield