# How to give a number value to a word in Python using lists

Tags: python, list

Ok, so I know for example you can just give the words value individually like
one=1
two=2
and so on, but if there was a lot of words, is there not an easier way to do this. I seem to remember you can do it with lists, but if you can I cant remember how.

Comment: What do you mean by _"words"_? Variables? Dictionary keys?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: Enumerations? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python. A dictionary with Key/Value pairs sounds like what you are looking for...

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python

Comment: Is python expected to correctly assign 23121 to the word "twenty_three_thousand_one_hundred_twenty_one"? Or should it be assigned to "two_three_one_two_one"? Similarly, would 10 be mapped to "ten" or "one_zero"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> one, two, three = [1,2,3]
```

In Python 3 you can also do:

```
>>> a, b, *others = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> others
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: in python two you can sort of do the same `(a,b),rest = a_list[:2],a_list[2:]`