# How to create an arbitrary number of dictionaries/lists (with different names) in python?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I'm trying to create #arb dictionaries like this:(arb = 2 or 4 or some number)

```
for n in xrange(0, arb):
    dictn = {}
```

However I realize that python doesn't take variables in the left side of equations.. So I'm confused. How can I have #arb dictionaries or lists with *different names*? like `list1` through `listn` or `dict1` through `dictn`.

I know this might sound stupid but I'm not good at program and terribly confused. Any suggestions would help, thanks

Comment: Just create a list of dictionaries

Comment: Create a dict container wich each key is the name's var

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to attempt to create variables like that. If you have a need to dynamically create multiple dictionaries or lists in one go, you should put them in a container. A list is fine for that, or if you have an idea for keys, then why not a dict?

Example:

```
>>> arb = 4
>>> dicts = [{} for _ in range(arb)]
>>> print(dicts)
[{}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Or a dictionary of dicts:

```
>>> arb = 4
>>> dicts = {"dict_{}".format(i): {} for i in range(arb)}
>>> print(dicts)
{'dict_0': {}, 'dict_1': {}, 'dict_2': {}, 'dict_3': {}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I could make this clear, but after creating the dicts I need to assign different values to them, say I need `line n` of a file to be the key of `distn`, thats why I'm trying naming them in such a vague way

Comment: @LilMuji I understand, are you having some issues on how to do that?

Comment: I got it.. The whole idea about dictionary still confuses me a lot. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Create a dict container wich each key is the name's var. Try this

```
container_dict = {}
arb= 4
for n in xrange(0, arb):
    #for dicts
    container_dict["dict%i" % n] = {}
    #for lists
    container_dict["list%i" % n] = []
```

%i will interpolate the index, so keys will be numered from 0 to arb-1

```
>>> container_dict
{'dict1': {}, 'dict0': {}, 'dict3': {}, 'dict2': {}, 'list1': [], 'list0': [], 'list3': [], 'list2': []}
```

Comment: %n was wrong, %i is correct. Have a look at last edit