# Naming DataFrames iteritively using items from a List + a string

Tags: python

I have a list of names of countries.. and I have a large dataframe where one of the columns is ' COUNTRY ' (yes it has a space before and after the word country) I want to be create smaller DataFrames based on country names

```
cleaned_df[cleaned_df[' COUNTRY ']==asia_country_list[1]]
```

seems too long a command to achieve this? It does work though.

Now,

```
str("%s_data" % (asia_country_list[1]))
```

gives

```
'Taiwan_data'
```

but when I combine the above two:

```
str("%s_data" % (asia_country_list[1])) = cleaned_df[cleaned_df[' COUNTRY ']==asia_country_list[1]]
```

I get:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

happy to learn other ways as well to achieve this pls.. Thanks vm

Comment: `str("%s_data" % (asia_country_list[1]))` is a function call - you cant assign values to a function/result. You may be looking for `cleaned_df[str("%s_data" % (asia_country_list[1]))] = [...]`. Can't tell if thats the case, where do you want to store what?

Comment: I assume you want to dynamically create variable names, in which case it might be easier to just add them to a dictionary. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Comment: @ M.T .. indeed want to dynamically create variable names.. tx vm for taking a look, have seen the solutions below as per marmouset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should do this, but if you really need it :

```
exec(str("%s_data" % (asia_country_list[1])) +"= cleaned_df[cleaned_df[' COUNTRY ']==asia_country_list[1]]")
```

should work.
Using a dictionary is likely to solve your problem

```
  D={}
  D["%s_data" % (asia_country_list[1]))]=cleaned_df[cleaned_df[' COUNTRY ']==asia_country_list[1]]]
```

EDIT : the first solution is a bad idea : exec is a dangerous command, if one column is named "del cleaned_df" you will actually execute it, it can get destructive. Typically I am guessing spaces are a problem in your case. It's a bit like SQL injections...

Comment: so that does it - both options work..  I have been reading that experts dont really like this - and you too mentioned 'don't think you shlould do this' .. why is i t? I  am a newb, so want to learn the thinking behind this pls

Thanks vm again for your help!

Comment: also - when I put this in a for loop:

'for country_name in len(asia_country_list):
   exec(str("%s_data" % (asia_country_list[country_name])) + "=cleaned_df[cleaned_df[' COUNTRY ']==asia_country_list[country_name]]")'

gives me the error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: v sorry for the spamming.. but the exec statement also doesnt work if the country name has a space in it:

Hong Kong_data=cleaned_df[cleaned_df[' COUNTRY ']==asia_country_list[0]]

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: your loop is wrong, as a start,  range(len(asia_country_list) is iterable, len(asia_country_list) is not

Comment: thanks vm.. range(len(asia_country_list) works fine.. this is my mistake.. will read up more on data structures