# Create a loop for a set of similar statements in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a 2D matrix called `A0`

```
A0 = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
```

I have a function called `newProb` which takes this as an argument and returns another 2D matrix in the following way:-

```
A1 = newProb(A0)
```

So, I want to put this code into a loop.

```
A1 = newProb(A0)
A2 = newProb(A1)
A3 = newProb(A2)
A4 = newProb(A3)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I have to make 100 calls to that function in the above way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating variable names on fly in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Comment: Why not just create a list, add the result of each call to the list, then on the next iteration use the previous list value? Or you could use recursion.

Comment: @SteveJ . yeah i will try that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to create local variables in your loop, you'd be better off storing the results in a list. Your list's index will line up nicely with your naming convention.

```
A = []

A.append([[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)])

A[1] = newProb(A[0])
A[2] = newProb(A[1])
# ...
```

You can then easily put this into a loop with a `range`.

```
# start the range off by 1
for i in range(1, 10):
    A[i] = newProb(A[i - 1])
```

This could also be written as

```
for i in range(10):
    A.append(newProb(A[i]))
```

Comment: `A[1]` will give you `IndexError` if elements of `A` are not pre-allocated.  Use `.append()` instead

Comment: You mean A[0] instead of A0 in the second line ?

Comment: I realized. I've fixed the logic by offsetting the range by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict`:

```
A = {}
A[0] = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
for i in range(1, 101):
    A[i] = newProb(A[i-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your values in a list generated like so:

```
A = [A0]
for i in range(99):
    A.append(newProb(A[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from @jez and @Soviut:

```
A = []
A.append([[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)])

for i in range(100):
    A.append(newProb(A[-1])
```

`A[-1]` is the last element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the 'final' value, after the 100st loop:

```
value = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
for i in range(100):
    value = newProb(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Round out the answers with a while loop

```
A = [A0]
while len(A) < 100:
    A.append(newProb(A[-1]))
```