# Python declare multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have more than 300 variables in a list and i have to make a list of each variables:

example:

```
x=['aze','qsd','frz']...
```

i want:

```
MAXaze=[]
MAXqsd=[]
MAXfrz=[]
...
```

without typing them

Thank you for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating variable names on fly in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Comment: Bear in mind that variable names in Python [cannot start with numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier).

Comment: `[[elm] for elm in x]`

Comment: better use dictionary - ie. `data["MAXaze"] = []` - it will be easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the values:

```
x=['aze','qsd','frz',...]
vars = {}
for i in x:
    vars["MAX" + i] = []
```

Or in order for them to become real variables you can add them to globals:

```
x=['aze','qsd','frz',...]
for i in x:
    globals()["MAX" + i] = []
```

You can now use:

```
MAXaze = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: except he says - **"i have to make a list of each variables:"**

Comment: x=['aze','qsd','frz',...]
for i in x:
    globals()[i] = 0

Comment: @NickA yes i  will i have to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to my mind is by using `exec`.
But be aware that there are [security issues](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/) related to `exec`.

```
x=['aze','qsd','frz']
for i in x:
    exec('{}=[]'.format(i))
```