# Assigning value to variable name in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>a=input("Enter Variable Value: ")
123abc321zxc
>>b=input("Enter Variable Name: ")
xyz
```

Now i want **xyz** to be considered as variable name and **123abc321zxc** as its value(value of 'a' to be assigned to value of b) so that i can get below result:

> > xyz="123abc321zxc"

**NOTE:** Use of database is not allowed. Its not a duplicate of any question. Please dont mark it duplicate

Please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating variable names on fly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Comment: No . Its not duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a variable with a dynamic name you can do:

```
globals()['var_name'] = 'var_value'
```

This worked for me:

```
>>> globals()[input("Enter Variable Name: ")] = input("Enter Variable Value: ")
Enter Variable Value: 123
Enter Variable Name: aabbcc
>>> print(aabbcc)
123
>>>
```

**EDIT**:

Let me know if this is fine with you:

```
>>> g = globals() # Get the *current global symbol table*.
>>> var_name = input("Enter Variable Name: ")
Enter Variable Name: aabbcc
>>> var_value= input("Enter Variable Value: ")
Enter Variable Value: 123
>> g[var_name] = var_value # Add to the *current global symbol table* a name (named as the value of the variable *var_name*, 'aabbcc' in this case) and value with the value of the variable *var_value*.
>>> print(aabbcc)
123
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry. But here its just a=b. It doesnot fulfill my purpose. Its just like that i am creating variable name from UI as 'xyz' and i get the value after certain operation. Now i want that value to be stored in xyz variable name(which is given from UI)

Comment: Thanks gsi-frank. This helped me. :)