# Python. How to dynamically create variables based on number of lines in a file?

Tags: python, file, variables

Is it possible to create variables based on the number of lines in a file?

For example, assuming the file will always have an even-number of lines. If the file has 4 lines I want to create 2 variables. `var1` will contain the first 2 lines and `var2` will contain the following 2 lines. If the file has 10 lines I want to create 5 variables. Again the first var will have the first 2 lines, and the next var will have the following 2 lines and so on...

Comment: It's certainly possible, but... why do you want to do this? How do you imagine you'll use these variables?

Comment: You should use a list...

Comment: "How do I dynamically create variables" is a very common beginner question, but the sane answer is almost always "use a dict" or "use a list". Search for duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating variable names on fly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost always a bad idea to create variable names based on some programmatic value.  Instead use a native data structure.  In this case it sounds like a `list` is what you need.

Here is a way to loop through a file and collect pairs of lines into a list of lists.

```
var = []
last_line = None
for line in open('data.txt', 'rU'):
    if last_line:
        var.append([last_line, line.strip()])
        last_line = None
    else:
        last_line = line.strip()
if last_line:
    var.append([last_line])
print(var)
```

#### Results:

```
[['line1', 'line2'], ['line3', 'line4'], ['line5', 'line6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('lines.txt'))
with open("lines.txt", "r+") as f:
    len_of_lines = num_lines
    count_ = 0
    while count_ < len_of_lines:
        var = list(islice(f, 2))
        # something with var
        print(var)
        count_ += 2
   >>>['xascdascac\n', 'ascascanscnas\n']
      ['ascaslkckaslca\n', 'ascascacac\n']
      ['ascascaca\n', 'ascacascaca\n']
      ['ascascascac\n']
```