# Python how do I assign some data to a variables value

Tags: python

Code snippet: 
`data = [("a", "b", "c", "d"),("e", "f", "g", "h")]
for i in data:
    console = '{}_{}'.join(('consoleip',str(i[2])))
    <> = Hostdata(hw_id = i[0],location_id = i[1],consoleip = i[2],          biosversion = i[3])`

Expected result:
`consolip_c = Hostdata(hw_id ='a', location_id ='b', consoleip ='c', biosversion ='d')
 consolip_g = Hostdata(hw_id ='e', location_id ='f', consoleip ='g', biosversion ='h')`

Im looping through the data, which holds thousands of database records and I want each record to be held in a distinct variable unique to the record. This would help me access each record with a unique named tuple variable.
How can I fill in the gap for `<>`, to assign a the `namedtuple(Hostdata)` to the value associated for console. Because I get a "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" when I directly use:

```
'{}_{}'.join(('consoleip',str(i[2]))) = Hostdata(hw_id = i[0],location_id = i[1],consoleip = i[2],biosversion = i[3])
```

Comment: Is *"the value associated for console"* a really weird way of saying you want to print out the resulting value to the terminal?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the expected result for a simple set of inputs. Code which doesn't do what you hope is a very poor way to communicate what you actually do hope to accomplish.

Comment: "How do I dynamically create variables" is a very common beginner question, but the sane answer is almost always "use a dict" or "use a list". Search for duplicates.

Comment: Okay thats correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python provided a solution to use a dict that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console=Hostdata(hw_id = i[0],location_id = i[1],consoleip = i[2],biosversion = i[3])
```

You are trying to assign the value to the value that the variable holds instead of the value to the variable. Basically, the <> is console.

Comment: `console = Hostdata(*i)` is enough?

Comment: I think so. He seems to want to assign the above value to a variable. Right now, he is assigning it to a value which you cannot do

Comment: Are you suggesting variable reassignment? I really want to achieve "assign the value to the value that the variable holds"

Comment: That's like saying *"I want `"foo" = "bar"` to succeed"*

Comment: Im not sure if understand the requirement here. If you look at the code Im looping through the result, which holds thousands of database records and I want each record to be held in a distinct variable unique to the record.

Comment: So you want a dictionary?