# Using an integer along with a letter in a command in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use an integer along with a letter to set a predefined variable to a number. I'm not quite sure how to explain this, so please see the code below...

```
from random import *
for i in range(0,playerDifficulty,1):
    tempRandomLine = randint(1, 10)
    l(tempRandomLine) = 15
```

Where I have the l(tempRandomLine), I need that to be able to set a variable predefined, such as l5, to 15, and I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any ideas? I am using Python 3

Comment: Use a *container* such a `list` or a `dict` instead of a bunch of numbered variables.

Comment: Instead of having a whole bunch of variables, instead store the data in a `list` or `dict`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating variable names on fly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list:

```
from random import *
l = [0] * 10
for i in range(0,playerDifficulty,1):
    tempRandomLine = randint(1, 10)
    l[tempRandomLine - 1] = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate create a separate variable for random numbers, concatenate that with the string, and then pass that as the parameter for your argument.

Answer (score -1):

try this out:

```
from random import *
playerDifficulty = 30

count = 0
listone = []
for i in range(0,playerDifficulty,1):
    count +=1
    if count <=15:
        tempRandomLine = randint(1, 10)
        l = 'l'+str(tempRandomLine) + str(count)
        listone.append(l)
    else:
        pass
print(listone)
```