# Why shouldn't one dynamically generate variable names in python?

Tags: python, oop

Right now I am learning Python and struggling with a few concepts of OOP, one of that being how difficult it is (to me) to dynamically initialize class instances and assign them to a dynamically generated variable name and why I am reading that I shouldn't do that in the first place.

In most threads with a similar direction, the answer seems to be that it is un-Pythonic to do that.

For example [generating variable names on fly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Could someone please elaborate?

Take the typical OOP learning case:

```
LOE = ["graham", "eric", "terry_G", "terry_J", "john", "carol"]
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, job="comedian"):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
```

Why is it better to do this:

```
employees = []
for name in LOE:
    emp = Employee(name)
    employees.append(emp)
```

and then

```
for emp in employees:
    if emp.name == "eric":
        print(emp.job)
```

instead of this

```
for name in LOE:
    globals()[name] = Employee(name)
```

and

```
print(eric.job)
```

Thanks!

Comment: p.s.: In writing this question, I think that I may have understood the reasoning behind this: 
My problem is that at the start of the program, I don't know all the names of the employees and thus cannot statically assign variable names for all the employees, but I seem to have assumed, that, when working with the employee-objects later in the program I somehow will know all the assigned variable names, when in reality i cannot.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: A fair comparison would be your approach vs. using a dictionary, not vs. using a list, and also using comprehensions. Your second code sample would become `employees = {name: Employee(name) for name in loe}`, and the third sample would become `print(employees['eric'].job)`.

Comment: This question, in my opinion, deserves a cross-language canonical answer. It's not specific to Python, but is asked multiple times a week, or day.

Comment: Though many times, the question is phrased as "I need 10 variables, `student_0` through `student_9`, how do I do that?". Even though these names *are* predictable, the answer is still the same - your program will be much more versatile and maintainable if you use a list variable `student`, and iterate over it to get all students, or index into it by integer list index.

Comment: @Paul The answer to that is often very simple and pragmatic: what's the difference between `student_0` and `students[0]`, except for the fact that the latter is easy with a variable for the index, and the former is somewhere between unnecessarily hard and impossible, depending on the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you dynamically generate variable names, you don't know what names exist, and you can't use them in code.

```
globals()[some_unknown_name] = Foo()
```

Well, now what? You can't safely do this:

```
eric.bar()
```

Because you don't know whether `eric` exists. You'll end up having to test for `eric`'s existence using dictionaries/lists anyway:

```
if 'eric' in globals(): ...
```

So just store your objects in a dictionary or list to begin with:

```
people = {}
people['eric'] = Foo()
```

This way you can also safely iterate one data structure to access all your grouped objects without needing to sort them from other global variables.

Comment: That is what I started to think when writing the question. Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

`globals()` gives you a `dict` which you can put names into.  But you can equally make your own `dict` and put the names there.

So it comes down to the idea of "namespaces," that is the concept of isolating similar things into separate data structures.

You should do this:

```
employees = {}
employees['alice'] = ...
employees['bob'] = ...
employees['chuck'] = ...
```

Now if you have another part of your program where you describe parts of a drill, you can do this:

```
drill['chuck'] = ...
```

And you won't have a name collision with Chuck the person.  If everything were global, you would have a problem.  Chuck could even lose his job.