# Create a variable with the name of the contents of another variable, with the contents of the other variables contents

Tags: python, variables

So i have code like this

```
varName = 'test'
varContents = 'something'
```

My question is:
How do i create a variable with the name of the contents of `varName`, having contents containing the contents of `varContents`?

Comment: Why do you want to create a variable dynamiclly ? How to you plan to use it after ? In generak that **is not** to create variable name dynamically, because the variable name represent nothing in fact

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't one dynamically generate variable names in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583955/why-shouldnt-one-dynamically-generate-variable-names-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you'll want to avoid doing this - especially if you are dealing with user inputs, but you can use the `exec()` function. It runs a string passed into it as code, so you can do something like:

```py
varName = 'test'
varContents = 'something'
exec(f"{varName} = '{varContents}'")
print(test)
```

A better way of storing data with a dynamic key is with a dict like this:

```py
myDict = {}
varName = 'test'
varContents = 'something'

myDict[varName] = varContents
print(myDict[varName])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create variables like this :

```
locals()['newVar'] = "local variable"
print (newVar)

globals()['newGlobalVar'] = "global variable"
print (newGlobalVar)
```

so you could do this :

```
locals()[varName] = varContents
# Or
globals()[varName] = varContents
```