# Scrapy Data Flow and Items and Item Loaders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy

I am looking at the [Architecture Overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/architecture.html) page in the Scrapy documentation, but I still have a few questions regarding data and or control flow.

***Scrapy Architecture***
[image]

***Default File Structure of Scrapy Projects***

```
scrapy.cfg
myproject/
    __init__.py
    items.py
    middlewares.py
    pipelines.py
    settings.py
    spiders/
        __init__.py
        spider1.py
        spider2.py
    ...
```

***item.py***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy

class MyprojectItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

which, I'm assuming, becomes

```
import scrapy

class Product(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    stock = scrapy.Field()
    last_updated = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
```

so that errors are thrown when trying to populate undeclared fields of `Product` instances

```
>>> product = Product(name='Desktop PC', price=1000)
>>> product['lala'] = 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
KeyError: 'Product does not support field: lala'
```

**Question #1**

Where, when, and how does our crawler become aware of `items.py` if we have created `class CrowdfundingItem` in `items.py`?

Is this done in...

- `__init__.py`?
- `my_crawler.py`?
- `def __init__()` of `mycrawler.py`?
- `settings.py`?
- `pipelines.py`?
- `def __init__(self, dbpool)` of `pipelines.py`?
- somewhere else?

**Question #2**

Once I have declared an item such as `Product`, how do I then store the data by creating instances of `Product` in a context similar to the one below?

```
import scrapy

class MycrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mycrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('-headless')
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
        browser.get(self.start_urls[0])
        elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//section')
        count = 0
        for ele in elements:
             name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('./div[@id="name"]').text
             price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('./div[@id="price"]').text

             # If I am not sure how many items there will be,
             # and hence I cannot declare them explicitly,
             # how I would go about creating named instances of Product?

             # Obviously the code below will not work, but how can you accomplish this?

             count += 1
             varName + count = Product(name=name, price=price)
             ...
```

Lastly, say we forego naming the `Product` instances altogether, and instead simply create unnamed instances.

```
for ele in elements:
    name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('./div[@id="name"]').text
    price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('./div[@id="price"]').text
    Product(name=name, price=price)
```

If such instances are indeed stored somewhere, where are they stored? By creating instances this way, would it be impossible to access them?

Answer (score 2):

Using an `Item` is optional; they're just a convenient way to declare your data model and apply validation. You can also use a plain `dict` instead.

If you do choose to use `Item`, you will need to import it for use in the spider. It's not discovered automatically. In your case:

```
from items import CrowdfundingItem
```

As a spider runs the `parse` method on each page, you can load the extracted data into your `Item` or `dict`. Once it's loaded, `yield` it, which passes it back to the scrapy engine for processing downstream, in pipelines or exporters. This is how scrapy enables "storage" of the data you scrape.

For example:

```
yield Product(name='Desktop PC', price=1000) # uses Item
yield {'name':'Desktop PC', 'price':1000} # plain dict
```

Comment: and for some reason it wasn't letting me `yield` dicts before. it was working fine with `-t basic`, but not `-t crawl` for some reason :/

Comment: i wouldn't mind learning how to use items if it's going to make my life easier later, especially when processing the scraped data and inserting it into the database.

Comment: well, of course i could `yield {}`, but when i try to run `scrapy crawl blah -o blah.json` it simply spits out a blank json file...

Comment: Whether using an `Item` or a `dict`, the yielded items will be available in a `pipeline` (which is where you can put your database storage logic), and to the `exporters` (which write them to `blah.json` in your example).

Comment: ok, then what is all of this "convenience" with Items that the documentation speaks of?

Comment: so, for the sake of clarification, once you yield an item, it's passed from the spider to the engine?!