# How do i create declare with multiple empty lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to input a number, and will create x amount of declared empty lists.

```
Ex: Input number >> 3
Result:
1 = []
2 = []
3 = []
```

So I am thinking convert the input str into int, then insert the int value into range (x). Then do a loop that can create x amount of number with '= []'. In my final work, I would want to take out the data stored in these list into different fields.

Below is code:

```
number = input("Input number")
number = int(number)

x = range (number)
for y in x.attributes:
    str(y) = []

#a loop that insert values in list into fields
driver.find_element_by_name('Name').send_keys(1[0])
driver.find_element_by_name('GRADE').send_keys(1[1])
driver.find_element_by_name('DATE').send_keys(1[2])

Error msg:
str(y) = []
^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
I think declared value should str, so I have str(y) there.
```

Appreciate the help with some short explain or what kind of guide i should look for.
Thanks

Comment: you could put the values in a `dict` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Values* (such as `3`, `"hello"`, `True`, `[]`, etc) are referenced by *variables*, which have a *name*. For example:

```
a = 4
```

`a` is a variable (whose name is "a"), and it references the `4` value.

Not all names are valid though. For example, "1" is not a valid name for a variable. How could the interpreter know that `1` is a variable and not a value?

Moreover, you can't assign a value to another value. I.e., you can't do something like this:

```
4 = True
```

It simply doesn't make any sense.

In your specific case, `str(y)` is an expression that returns a value. For example, if `y=3` then `str(y)` would return `"3"`. Being a value, you can't assign to it another value! I.e., you can't do

```
str(y) = []
```

Instead, you might want to create a variable (with a proper name) and assign a value to it.

If you really want to create a variable with a name generated at runtime, you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python) question. It is not recommended though. Instead, you might want to create an array of values:

```
arr = []
for i in range(100):
    arr.append([])
# arr[i] is your i-th variable
```

Comment: Thx for the detailed explain! This really helps and point me out the path