# How can I do it with for loop (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

It's a simple question, but I can't find the solution.
How can I do it with for loop? (In a shorter way.)

```
nfo1 = str(nfolist[0])
nfo2 = str(nfolist[1])
nfo3 = str(nfolist[2])
nfo4 = str(nfolist[3])
nfo5 = str(nfolist[4])
nfo6 = str(nfolist[5])
nfo7 = str(nfolist[6])
nfo8 = str(nfolist[7])
nfo9 = str(nfolist[8])
nfo10 = str(nfolist[9])
nfo11 = str(nfolist[10])
```

Comment: I think you should see this old question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Check out this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python/10182903

Comment: Use a `list` for storing the result, instead of collection of variables.

Comment: `list(map(str, nfolist))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(11):
  locals()[f'nfo{i + 1}'] = str(nfolist[i])
```

but it’s a bit ugly

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use a dictionary:

```
nfo = {}
for x in range(11):
  nfo['nfo'+str(x)]=str(nfolist[x])
```

The dictionary `nfo`:

```
{'nfo0': '0',
 'nfo1': '1',
 'nfo2': '2',
 'nfo3': '3',
 'nfo4': '4',
 'nfo5': '5',
 'nfo6': '6',
 'nfo7': '7',
 'nfo8': '8',
 'nfo9': '9',
 'nfo10': '10'}
```

To get a value from the dict (suppose want `nfo['nfo4']`):

```
print(nfo['nfo4'])
```