# Change variable name using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want to make a variable with help of a function that gets its name from an argument, so that if I run this;

```
hi_var(abc)
print(abc)
```

I will get *hi* as output

I currently have this, but it is completely not working;

```
def hi_var(var_name):
  text = "hi"
  return text as var_name
```

It would be great if someone knew how to do this

Comment: This is not possible in Python, in general. It also isn't really desirable or necessary.

Comment: So, why not just `abc = hi_var()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [generating variable names on fly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Do you want ``hi_var(abc)`` to be equivalent to ``abc = "hi"``? What do you expect to happen when ``hi_var`` is used in a class or function scope, or in another expression – which namespace should the variable be set in? Is there any reason why you do not just use the equivalent assignment statement or expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but if you like you can access the global variable directory and add the variable there:

```
def hi_var(var_name):
    text = 'hi'
    globals()[var_name] = text

hi_var('abc')
print(abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Querenker's solution will work, but generally speaking it's not great to use global variables. It gets a bit messy. Also unit testing can get tricky.

I think it would be better to store everything somewhere specific.

eg:

```
dynamic_goodies = {}

def hi_var(var_name):
  text = "hi"
  dynamic_goodies[var_name] = text
  return text

hi_var(`abc`)
print(dynamic_goodies['abc'])
```

If this doesn't solve it for you can you add a little more info to your question? Why do you want to do this thing?

Comment: ``locals`` at global scope *is* ``globals``. In recent Python versions, changes to function``locals`` do not actually change values of variables.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks, I learned something from your comment

Answer (score 0):

In python, module variables which includes the REPL gets stored in a dictionary called globals(). Typing `globals()` into the console will show the dictionary.

Although, the question being not so clear to me, as far I understood you needed a function that can assign values to variables. So, here's an example of such a function.

```
def cv(var_name, value='hi'): 
    """
    create varibles
    """
    globals()[var_name] = value

cv('h')
print(h)
```

Output:

```
hi
```

Comment: Variables are *not* all stored in the ``globals`` dictionary. Only module variables, which includes the REPL, are stored in ``globals``. Python knows *at least* three other kinds of variables, namely (function) local, closure and class.